# Can’t send mail with PHP

Tags: php, html, forms, email

I want to be able to send what a user enters in a textfield to my email by PHP, but when I click the “submit” button the page refreshes, the textfield clears, and no email is sent to my email address.

Here is my PHP:

```
<?php
$mail = $_POST['mail'];
$formcontent = "Email: $mail";
$recipient = "angrybullet2.webhosting@gmail.com";
$subject = "Mail that uploaded picture";
$mailheader = "From: my website";

mail($recipient, $subject, $formcontent, $mailheader) or die("Error!");
echo 'OK ! Your mail address has been successfully added to your photo !<br>We will contact you later :)';
?>
```

Here is my HTML:

```
<html>
<body bgcolor="lightpink">
  <div align="center">
    <font face="helvetica" size="5px" color="#009933">
      Your photos has been successfully uploaded !<br>Enter your email address to tell you how to win the $50 000 !
    </font>
    <form name="form" id="login" method="POST" action="up_ok_send_mail.php">
      <input type="text" name="mail" id="mail" size="70" placeholder="Enter your email address here">
      <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="submit">
    </form>
</body>
  </div>
</html>
```

I don’t know what’s happening. I tried to web host this HTML with this PHP in a directory apart from the rest of my website’s parts (including the `print_r` function that [Mohan suggested me to add](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23171328/cant-send-mail-with-php#comment35484094_23171460)). And everything is great, but when this HTML is linked to a page that has to be before it, the whole thing does not work. When submitting the email the page refreshes and no email is sent to my email address.

---

Okay. It worked. I managed to fix my problem by making the email submission field in the same HTML file that it was linked to. I mean there is no more links to this page. Everything is on the same HTML now.

Comment: Is this running on localhost?

Comment: @ElliotFehr he is using the native `mail` function from php. the error he may have is that is running in localhost, or some other error, do you get any error?

Comment: Try to add a full file path into action=""

Comment: Put an echo "test";die(); at the top of your php file, just to see if you even get there when submitting the form.

Comment: If you are using your localhost, then you have to set your default smtp port to send the mail. You can use phpmailer to test. http://phpmailer.worxware.com/index.php?pg=examplebsmtp

Comment: no I am actually web hosting using 000webhost.com

Answer (score 0):

Form is not submiting or if you work in localhost you won't have smtp protocol to send mail check whether form is submitting to up_ok_send_mail.php page

Comment: no I am not local hosting i am web hosting using 000webhost.com

Comment: and yes the form is not submitting. when i click on submit it refreshes the page

Comment: write this code in up_ok_send_mail.php print_r($_POST);exit; check whether value getting to that page or not